# So. I need to copy a line of text from Windows NotePad and paste into an Xfce /Terminator Window

Tags: linux, windows, clipboard, gnome-terminator

I have a long and complex line of text in Windows 10/Notepad.  I want to copy/paste or use key combos to insert it in a Ubuntu/Terminator window. (Terminator is running in Xfce, accessed via Remote Desktop Connection.)  I swear I did this a long time ago, but I cant remember how :-( Any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Easiest may be to install `dos2unix` utility if you don't already have it (I don't think it's a default install on Ubuntu). You can get it into your clipboard & pipe your text through `dos2unix`; e.g. `xclip -o | dos2unix`, or save it to a file & use `dos2unix file.txt`.